# Scheduling a job in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `Leave_info` table in that there are 4 columns:

> empid, Cl, SL, LOP

The default value at the beginning of every year for CL,SL,LOP is

> 12, 6, 0.

This update has to be done automatically by the server on every year Jan 1st 12am. How to do this?

Comment: Do you need help creating the job, or writing the update?

Comment: Btw looks like 4 columns...

Comment: there are 3 columns `empid, Cl, SL, LOP` ??

Comment: I want to update the table but it has to done automatically. User should not type the update command

Answer (score 0):

If your server has `SQL Server Agent` installed, you can create a `job` and schedule it to run at 12:00am on the 1st of each year.

Here's a quick how-to on creating a `job`:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx

If you do not have `SQL Server Agent` installed then you can write an application, compile it, and then set a `Windows Scheduled Task` on the server to run your application based on your needed yearly schedule.

( Or cron job in Linux environment if not MS SQL Server )